# Not specifying vector type when appending to a map in c++?

Tags: c++, syntax

Say you have a map of `int` mapped to vectors and you want to add to it in C++. Could you add to it using `{{}}` instead of specifying the type?

For example, is:

```
int x = 10;
int z = 0;
int t = 20;
int y = 30;
int sum = y + z;

unordered_map<int,vector<vector<int>>> my_map;
my_map[sum] = {{x, t}};
```

equivalent to:

```
my_map[sum] = vector<vector<int>>{{x,t}};
```

Comment: No, it's not equivalent to anything, because that is not valid C++. No self-respecting C++ compiler will accept such code.

Comment: If your motivation for asking is to make it easier to write code like the latter example, then consider using a typedef... _e.g._ `typedef vector<vector<int>> NastyType`.  Then you can write `foo[sum] = NastyType{{x,t}}`.  You may also consider [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace).

Comment: I was asking this question because I saw it written with just brackets when reviewing solutions to an algorithm problem I was working on...I understand it is not preferable.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that is actually (almost) valid C++ code, apart from forgetting to name the map. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a40945155f90a15

Comment: "Almost" is never good enough for C++. Either it's valid, or not. There is no "almost valid".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik their particular question is valid syntax. The preamble isn't, but that wasn't what they were asking about, and your comment implies (incorrectly) that their question has no basis in reality.